# Image wont fit into div properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap-3

so what I'm trying to accomplish is to have a large image, in this case a map, inside a smaller div with scroll bars that let you look at the rest of the map. I'm using class="img-responsive" at the moment but it makes the image the same size as the div which i do not want since when the user is looking for a road if the map is too small they wont be able to see it. I also tried to set a max-height for the div but the image is overflowing onto the background. Please help.

```css
.ibox-content {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: inherit;
  padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
  border-color: #e7eaec;
  border-image: none;
  border-style: solid solid none;
  border-width: 1px 0px;
  max-height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ibox-content" id="ibox-1">
  <div class="active content" id="elementMap">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="//lorempixel.com/600/600">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `img-responsive`, because it gives the style `max-width: 100%` to the element, meaning the image can never be wider than its parent.

Add `overflow: auto;` to the container:

```
.ibox-content {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: inherit;
    padding: 15px 20px 20px 20px;
    border-color: #e7eaec;
    border-image: none;
    border-style: solid solid none;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    max-height:350px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: instead of changing the CSS for all, I just added style="overflow:auto" giving ```<div  style="overflow:auto" class="ibox-content" id="ibox-1">```

Answer (score 1):

Div with overflow: scroll or overflow: auto will solve your problem.